# MSSQL-AZURE-EDGE sqlcmd not found

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, apple-m1

I have docker file, which only download azure-edge latest image and accept EULA with starting of sqlserver & sqlcmd. But during starting it throws exception, that sqlcmd not found. I tried to up container without accepting of EULA, to check if sqlcmd exists. And it wasn't downloaded. Can't figure out, why)
Works on Mac M1

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/disconnected-deployment#connect-to-azure-sql-edge): *"sqlcmd tool is not available inside the ARM64 version of SQL Edge containers."* Which image are you using, as the ARM one doesn't require sqlcmd.